# laravel 5.5 duda al mostrar objeto o array en vista

Tags: sql, laravel, controller

soy nuevo en laravel 5.5 (apenas unas semanas) tengo una duda y todo comienza con un consulta sql dentro del InstitucionController...

```
 public function show($id)
  {
    $caso_estudio = CasoEstudio::find($id);
    $institucion = Institucion::find($id);
    $aux_id = $id;
    $sql_ce_id = "select * from casos_estudios 
                  left join instituciones ON institucion_id = instituciones.id 
                  where institucion_id = '$aux_id'";    
    DB::select($sql_ce_id);
    $ce_id = DB::select($sql_ce_id);
    $caso_e = (object)$ce_id;
    // dd($ce_id);
    // dd($caso_e);
    // dd($institucion);
    return view('instituciones/show', compact('institucion','caso_estudio','caso_e','ce_id'));
  }
```

si se fijan tengo tres dd cometados, pues necesito que la data se muestre como en el dd($institucion)...

```
  Institucion {#204 ▼
    #table: "instituciones"
    #fillable: array:13 [▶]
    #connection: "pgsql"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:16 [▶]
    #original: array:16 [▶]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
```

con dd($ce_id)...

```
  array:1 [▼
    0 => {#202 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"institucion_id": 1
      +"fec_envio": "1"
      +"fec_respuesta": null
      +"num_entrega": null
      +"num_oficio_siss": null
      +"num_exp_supervision": null
      +"cot_tesoro": false
      +"cot_banavih": false
      +"cot_ivss": false
      +"aport_trabajador": null
      +"aport_patron": null
      +"fijos_act": null
      +"contratados_act": null
      +"otros_act": null
      +"jubiladas": null
      +"jubilados": null
      +"jubilados_bs_anual": null
      +"pensionadas_i": null
      +"pensionados_i": null
      +"pensionados_i_bs_anual": null
      +"pensionadas_s": null
      +"pensionados_s": null
      +"pensionados_s_bs_anual": null
      +"observaciones": null
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
      +"estado_id": null
      +"municipio_id": null
      +"parroquia_id": null
      +"status": true
      +"acronimo": ""
      +"nom": "ALCALDÍA DEL MUNICIPIO CARIPE ESTADO MONAGAS"
      +"rif": "200067667"
      +"naturaleza": ""
      +"email": "ALCALDÍA1"
      +"tlf1": "2925451638"
      +"tlf2": "4166853121"
      +"tlf3": "4166853181"
      +"direccion": "AV. ENRIQUE CATTUMER. EDIFICIO ALCALDÍA. MUNICIPIO CARIPE. EDO. MONAGAS"
    }
  ]
```

y por ultimo dd($caso_e);

```
  {#203 ▼
    +"0": {#202 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"institucion_id": 1
      +"fec_envio": "1"
      +"fec_respuesta": null
      +"num_entrega": null
      +"num_oficio_siss": null
      +"num_exp_supervision": null
      +"cot_tesoro": false
      +"cot_banavih": false
      +"cot_ivss": false
      +"aport_trabajador": null
      +"aport_patron": null
      +"fijos_act": null
      +"contratados_act": null
      +"otros_act": null
      +"jubiladas": null
      +"jubilados": null
      +"jubilados_bs_anual": null
      +"pensionadas_i": null
      +"pensionados_i": null
      +"pensionados_i_bs_anual": null
      +"pensionadas_s": null
      +"pensionados_s": null
      +"pensionados_s_bs_anual": null
      +"observaciones": null
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
      +"estado_id": null
      +"municipio_id": null
      +"parroquia_id": null
      +"status": true
      +"acronimo": ""
      +"nom": "ALCALDÍA DEL MUNICIPIO CARIPE ESTADO MONAGAS"
      +"rif": "200067667"
      +"naturaleza": ""
      +"email": "ALCALDÍA1"
      +"tlf1": "2925451638"
      +"tlf2": "4166853121"
      +"tlf3": "4166853181"
      +"direccion": "AV. ENRIQUE CATTUMER. EDIFICIO ALCALDÍA. MUNICIPIO CARIPE. EDO. MONAGAS"
    }
  }
```

ojo estoy conciente que tengo fallas conceptuales, pero voy aprendiensobre la marcha, y como comente al comienzo necesito que estas variables $ce_id o $caso_e, me guarden la informacion de la tabla como lo hace $institucion, pues de esta forma se como mostrarla en la vista... de ante mano muchas gracia a lo que se toment la moeleti de ayudarme

Comment: ¿Qué duda tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Por que no utilizas Eloquent, ya que la llamada es mas sencilla, por lo que veo tienes un modelo de CasoEstudio, y no hagas la llamada por sql.

```
CasoEstudio::where('id', $id)->where('institucion', ON)->where('instituciones_id', $aux_id)->get();
```

Te devolvera una coleccion que tendras que iterar con un foreach.

Answer (score -1):

En mi opinión te recomiendo:

Hacer las respectivas relaciones en tus modelos ya que si estas están bien establecidas puedes ir en cualquier dirección de la relación es decir de padre a hijo o de hijo a padre, ya que observo que en los atributos relations: `[]` no tienes nada y en algunos casos no aparecen las relaciones. practica mas Eloquent y como hacer las relaciones:

- belongsTo
- hasMany
- etc ...

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.